# Watson Assistant does not transfer conversations correctly in Intercom

Tags: chatbot, watson-assistant, intercom

I'm developing a chatbot on the Watson Assistant platform, currently with the "Plus trial" plan.

I am using the integration with Intercom, as it is offered by Watson Assistant.

The chatbot has its own seat and inbox in Intercom and the conversations between the users and the bot have no problem. The problem appears when I want to transfer the conversations from the bot to another specific human agent in Intercom.

To do this, I have followed the instructions in the Watson Assistant documentation (https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-intercom#deploy-intercom-config-backup).

The default team inbox to receive transferred messages is set to the "Unassigned". Then I have created a rule that states that for a specific dialog branch the conversation should be transferred to a specific agent. The transfers are triggered with a "Connect to human agent" action in the dialog branch specified in the rule.

Unfortunately this setup does not work. The transfers do happen, but to the unassigned inbox, not to the inbox of the agent specified in the rule.

How could I make this setup work?

More information :

No code is involved in this integration. I attach two screenshots from the relevant configuration pages in Watson.

[Home page of the Intercom integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSzCn.png)

[Page of the transfer settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi4Yk.png)

Comment: Hi! Can you share some code or screenshots of your set-up to make it easier to find the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I've added two screenshots.